# Html table colspan / rowspan

Tags: html, css

can someone send me code for this table, I can't find a solutions

```
<div class="table">
        <h3>Table</h3>
        <table class="table1" border="5">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">1</td>
                <td colspan="2">1 red </td>
                <td rowspan="3">2 red </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">2</td>
                <td>2 red</td>
                <td>3 red</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Treci red</td>
                <td>Treci red</td>
                <td>Treci red</td>
                <td>Treci red</td>  
            </tr>
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Nobody will code for you... i'll suggest to try to code and then ask here providing a [mcve]. Remember don't use table for layout purpose.

Comment: Did you check the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#complicated_tables)?

Comment: You cant use colspand and rowspan and still have more td's, when you add colspan/rowspan, you have to delete corresponding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a table that looks like that.

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 20.0242%;">
    <col style="width: 20.0242%;">
    <col style="width: 20.0242%;">
    <col style="width: 20.0242%;">
    <col style="width: 19.9032%;">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you are a beginner, or new to HTML, you could easily use a WYSIWYG editor to create a table like this.
Try https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/ as an example.

I'd suggest learning HTML and understanding how the markup works though.

Comment: Here is another example that matches more accurately to your request: https://codepen.io/treckstar_/pen/zYpVwZN